# Manga about the son of a blacksmith, whose mother died

Tags: story-identification, manga

A few years ago I read this manga/manhua/webtoon about a boy who lived in a medieval era type setting with his father being a drunk blacksmith after his wife died, the son at the age of 12 goes to the ceremony for coming of age, during the ceremony he discovers that he has a very high aptitude but for will-grass (or something similar) and considered useless.

After going to a school and a professor saw his aptitude he secretly trained the boy and helped him become OP with monsters with rings colors.

Later in the story, it's revealed the son's aptitude is the same as his mother's and his father is a legendary blacksmith fighter.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to find the manga, it is called [Soul Land](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-47804).

> Tang San spent his life in the Tang Outer Sect, dedicated to the
>   creation and mastery of hidden weapons. Once he stole the secret lore
>   of the Inner Sect to reach the pinnacle of his art, his only way out
>   was death. But after throwing himself off the deadly Hell's Peak he
>   was reborn in a different world, the world of Douluo Dalu, a world
>   where every person has a spirit of their own, and those with powerful
>   spirits can practice their spirit power to rise and become Spirit
>   Masters.
>
> The spirit that awakens within Tang San is Blue Silver Grass, a
>   useless spirit. Can he overcome the difficulties to reach the high
>   ranks of Spirit Masters and bring the glory of the Tang Sect into this
>   new world?

Comment: Glad you found it! If it's okay with you, could you self-accept your answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons? You should be able to do that in two days. Please do - it helps this site to be organized :)

Comment: It may be worth noting that the manga is based on a Chinese light novel for which there is a completed English translation freely available on the web.