# Manga about a boy who becomes an apprentice blacksmith and makes two hammers that he uses as weapons

Tags: story-identification, manga

A five or eight year old boy becomes an apprentice blacksmith to his uncle. He is able to use this technique that refines this really hard to work metal and his uncle has him turn it into two hammers that weigh 300-500kgs. He then moves to go to school and uses those hammers as weapons.

It was in full color and involved magic and something about building mechs or something.

Any ideas on the name of the manga?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, aside from the boy being strong enough to carry 300-500 kg hammers, was there any magic in this story, or any monsters?

Comment: Possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220739 . It has an answer, but no details, so it's hard to tell if it's correct. Assuming it even is the same.

Comment: I remembered something about him having a something blue grass thing then through a gotcha game gets a little green snake thing that he fuses with and he's able to summon the grass to bind ppl

Comment: Figured it out thank you for helping me jog my memory and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Was soul land 3

Comment: @JustTheTipGaming: You can post that as a self-answer, and then accept it. I'm going to post a placeholder, since comments aren't searchable, but let me know when you post your answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Oh, and of course, feel free to copy any and all of my answer for yours.

Answer (score 2):

The querent confirmed that the story they were looking for was *[Douluo Dalu 3: Longwang Chuanshuo](https://myanimelist.net/manga/111279/Douluo_Dalu_3__Longwang_Chuanshuo)*, aka *Soul Land 3: Legend of the Dragon King*.

[image: Front cover of Douluo Dalu 3: Longwang Chuanshuo]

> Following the advancement of spirit technology, the humans of Douluo Continent conquered the ocean and discovered two new continents. After being hunted by spirit masters excessively, the spirit beasts are nearly extinct. After countless years of lying dormant, the King of the Spirit Beasts has awakened in the Great Star Dou Forest. It will lead its remaining clansmen in taking vengeance against humanity!
>
> Tang Wu Lin is determined to become a powerful Spirit Master. However, when he awakened his martial spirit, it was actually an...
>
> Incomparable talent. The battle of the Dragon King. The Legend of our Dragon King hereby begins.

From [the webnovel](https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/legend-of-the-dragon-king/ldk-chapter-31), the hammers:

> At first glance, the pair of Thousand Refined Heavy Silver Hammers didn’t appear eye-catching. Their grey exterior made them appear like ordinary forging hammers. Upon closer inspection however, one would discover dark, wave-like patterns covering its whole body. The dark wavy patterns on the handle even seemed to be nurturing an endless strength.

....

> He had already conducted a series of measurements after forging them. The hammer in his left hand weighed 152 kilograms while the hammer in his right hand weighed 166 kilograms. Although these hammers appeared small, their weight could definitely be described by using one word: astonishing.

He subsequently takes his Blacksmith Ranking Test in [chapter 41](https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/legend-of-the-dragon-king/ldk-chapter-41). His [Second Ranking test](https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/legend-of-the-dragon-king/ldk-chapter-43) has him forging a component for a mecha.

> Tang Wulin had crafted a semi-circular component, an important component within the knee joint of a mecha. Joint protection components were most susceptible to wear and tear, however, this also made them the most suitable to be used for soul guide arrays. Heavy Silver was a good conductor for transmitting soul power. Thus, forging the joint component out of Heavy Silver would be the most appropriate. Tang Wulin had indeed considered these points prior to his forging.

Oh, and addressing a detail from the comments, it's [Bluesilver Grass](https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/legend-of-the-dragon-king/ldk-chapter-2)

> “Bluesilver Grass?” The Spirit Master’s voice exuded disappointment, but it was once again substituted with amazement in a moment. He had seen the Bluesilver Grass martial soul so many times before, this was a completely ordinary martial soul! Bluesilver Grass was so common that it covered the whole Douluo Continent as well as the Star Luo Continent and Heaven Dou Continent. Even the lawn of Red Mountain Academy was covered in Bluesilver Grass. How could this type of trash martial soul give birth to soul power?

And a [Grass Snake](https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/legend-of-the-dragon-king/ldk-chapter-19)

> Grass Snake? This wasn’t even a question of its strength, but whether or not it was actually a spirit soul.

Comment: Just noting that the first *Soul Land* came up in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194509/manga-about-the-son-of-a-blacksmith-whose-mother-died?rq=1