# A manga/manhwa where the mc is a light element user and has a companion beast of white dragon but it looks like a snake right at the beginning?

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

MC is a young boy in a pretty remote place where he meets a teacher who trains him then sponsors/takes him to go to the academy.

Comment: What did the teacher train the boy in? How to use his light magic? And was the academy a magic academy? Also, do you recall the boy's hair colour?

Answer (score -1):

***[Soul Land III](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/douluo-dalu-3-the-legend-of-the-dragon-king)*** is what it is, I believe.

> With advancements in soul technology, humans on the continent of Douluo conquered the oceans and discovered two new continents. The soul beasts have also been hunted to the brink of extinction by human soul masters. The king of soul beasts awakens in the depths of the Great Star Dou Forest to lead remaining clan members to seek vengeance against humankind! Tang Wulin aspires to be a powerful soul master, but when his martial soul awakens, it turns out to be…, Prodigy of an era, battle of the Dragon King, the legend of the Dragon King henceforth begins.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _Soul Land III_ matches the manga/manhwa described in the question. It'd help other users decide how likely this answer is to be correct or not.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/274972/manga-about-a-boy-who-becomes-an-apprentice-blacksmith-and-makes-two-hammers-tha?noredirect=1&lq=1, which was accepted in a comment.